# Search in multiple columns with multiple values postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║     name      ║        categories        ║        descriptoin        ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ Circuit large ║ electronics, accessories ║ electornics product 13vol ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

I am adding search functionality.
The user can search like `electronics circuit 13vol`

I need to search in 3 columns `name, categories, description` and show the result.

I am using Postgresql
What will be the query and index.
I tried full text search, LIKES etc. but it searches only 1 column for the whole search input.

Please help

Comment: You can make full text search include everything from multiple columns, that might be the easiest way. Just tell it to index the concatenated text.

Comment: The [FTS documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html) contains great examples on how to use multiple columns in it (you can even give each column a "weight" for a more advanced ranking). Did you try it? Is there something explicit which you are stuck on?